# How can I build a high voltage (2-6 kV), high frequency (20-50 kHz) power supply?

Tags: high-voltage, flyback, high-frequency

I need to make a high voltage (2-6 kV), high frequency (20-50 kHz) power supply in order to generate cold plasma (in argon gas.) I used a flyback circuit (found on the web.) The high frequency is generated by the self oscillating flyback transformer.

[image]

I made a transformer myself, with 3000 turns on the secondary and (4+4) on the primary and everything works. The input is 12V and I  get about 5 kV output at 10-30 kHz. The problem is that the oscillating frequency depends on the ferite core and the number of turns in the flyback transformer (e.g.: 4+4 or 5+5,) making it difficult to control.

I have few questions:

1. Can I achieve my goal with an IC to generate the high frequency pulse and feed it to my transformer? That way, I can control the oscillating frequency will.
2. I found a circuit online using 555 timer IC, but it is for a car ignition. Will it work in my case? If not, what do I need to change in the circuit?

[image]

3. I find that the flyback transformer is used much more commonly that an IC controlled one (like in a plasma ball). Why is that? Is it more efficient?

Comment: 1. Not only can, you should! 2. You need to modify several things, rectification and smoothing on the output and a mean for regulation. Save yourself the trouble and get yourself a proper flyback IC. 3. Regulation and overcurrent protection to name a few. Stay away from 555.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have little experience in IC circuit. Could you please give more detail what exactly and how should I change in the circuit (2) to achieve my goal. And which IC should I use to generate the oscilating frequency (20-50Khz)? Thanks alot.

Comment: UCC28740 springs to mind, but there are literally hundreds of others to choose from.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use flyback topology here, because the reflected voltage will damage your SWITCH.

Comment: Thank you. Are you mentioning circuit (1) or (2)? For circuit (1), everything works and I could run for 10 minutes continuously without anything damage. For circuit (2) it is not a flyback transformer.

Comment: Why would it? -1